# why return part in getDerivedStateFromProps are executed first then adressComponents variable is getting the value in the below code

Tags: react-native

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.region !== state.region) {
        var addressComponents='';

         Geocoder.from(props.region.latitude, props.region.longitude).then( json => {
           addressComponents = json.results[0].formatted_address
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error))



      return {
        address: addressComponents,
      };
    }
```

I want here that when addressComponents variable is updated then only return is executed.In this return is executed first then adressComponents Variable is getting the value .i am unable to wrap this as asynchronously